# How can I download a entire folder and hisub-folder with forge API from BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am a beginner and try to use the Autodesk Forge DATA MANAGEMENT API to create a beginner thing.

I want to create an archive of one bim360 folder with throught the forge API.

When I want to download one file there is no problem. (Find the hub, find the folder, find the version then get the file)
But when time arrives to download a full folder and its subfolders etc. I don't find a way to do that ?

Comment: Hi Simon, unfortunately, there is not API to get hierarchy of folders. you would have to iterate GET:Folder Contents (filter out with type=folders) one by one. However, what you need is to get all files/items within folder and subfolder, Search API 
 can of help. It filters the data of a folder and recursively in the subfolders: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/

Comment: Recursion is key here, write out what steps the program needs to undertake to get to your goal. Find out what data the endpoint needs and design your recursive function around that.

Comment: Thanks you guys, I'll try to achieve it with recursion ;)

Comment: Hi @XiaodongLiang, I'm trying to implement the search for bim360 docs but I keep getting 403 error. the forge app is added to the project and I can use API to access files/folders or recursively traverse folders, but the search keeps giving me this error. any suggestions? thanks.